# Merge data from multiple files

Tags: jquery, html, regex, notepad++

I have around 40k HTML files. They are all the same except some data inside.

I want to merge this inside one file only with data I need:

```
id  username  points
```

Here is part of HTML code:

```
<h1>
  <span class="user">
  <span class="uname">__username__</span>
  <span class="user-rating">(9211)</span>
</h1>
```

Plus one more information from different div:

```
<li class="active">
 <a href="/show_user.php?uid=3357863"><span>ID</span></a>
</li>
```

I was thinking to download all HTML files using httrack and later maybe use Notepad++ to move selected span to one file.

Comment: Is this a cache file ? Why are you using as many files ? HTML should be generated when needed or cached.

Comment: No, I want to create user database in one file with id,username and points. For example, lets say I want to merge all users from stackoverflow and I'll search for files starting from http://stackoverflow.com/users/1

Comment: What is the actual question? Why can't you do this using server side includes? Not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What if you first removed the excess HTML so that only ID, username, and points remain? You could then just iterate through the files.

Comment: And why dont you export them to a DBMS then ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex for capturing the elements you wish to have:

```
/"uname">(.*)<.*|\s*"user-rating">\((\d+)\)<.*|\s*uid=(\d+)/g
```

result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `__username__`
MATCH 2
2.  `9211`
MATCH 3
3.  `3357863`
```

Here's [a link](https://regex101.com/r/bN0mN9/1) for testing the regex.

edit:

Maybe I missunderstood, if you want to get the ID within the span not the "uid" in the "href" you should use the following if the ID is a number:

```
/"uname">(.*)<.*|\s*"user-rating">\((\d+)\)<.*|\s*uid=\d+"><span>(\d+)/g
```

If it can be a word too you should use this:

```
/"uname">(.*)<.*|\s*"user-rating">\((\d+)\)<.*|\s*uid=\d+"><span>(\w+)/g
```